# At this moment vs At this time

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

What is the difference between “At this moment” and “At this time”? I’ve heard the first one on a series and I think it means “now”, could “At the moment” be used instead?

Comment: I’m asking if “At this moment” could be interchangeable with “at the moment”. And Does “at this moment” mean the same as “at this time”?

Comment: "At the/this moment" usually mean "right now". "At this time" usually refers to a longer period that includes the present.

Comment: It is not uncommon to say “at this moment in time” too, which has always struck me as overkill. While @KateBunting is correct, my feeling is that these expressions all overlap to quite a considerable extent. Only context can tell us which to use.

Comment: _Now_ is preferable. And shorter.

Answer (score 1):

*At this/the moment* and *at this time* mean roughly the same thing: right now; in the present. However, they carry different connotations.

> X is true at the moment.

This means that X is true at the instant when the speaker says this. However, it suggests that X is likely to change soon. I might say "I'm home *at the moment*, but I'll be at work in an hour."

> X is true at this time.

This also means that X is true at the instant when the speaker says this. However, it suggests that X is likely to take a long time to change. I might say "Our company cannot give any refunds *at this time*." This is a more formal, heavy phrase, and it is often used when denying a request: a politician might say "I can't comment on that *at this time*."